# Obtain value of list and its index mentioned together in a String in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=["zubin","viral","rushil"]
param=["x[0]","x[1]","x[2]"]
for paramValue in param:
    p=paramValue # here i want to read "x[0]" and want to obtain value "zubin"
    print(p) # This should print "zubin"
```

I want to read param and get the value of X list 
Your's Thankful

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` or `eval` may help.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the index and the value you can use enumerate in pyhon

```
for index, paramValue in enumerate(param):
    p=paramValue
    i = index
```

Comment: Actually in the situation that i got stuck is that, the parameter is coming from the database in the string format eg. {'mapSMBFEIN':  {'param': ['fileToProcessRecord[columnLookup["etlfilename "]]']} } , Here i have the list of parameters for a function name mapSMBFEIN.

Comment: hmm therefore you could either try to extract the number of the format string or eval as suggested by @jpp

Answer (score 1):

You should find a better way to reference your list, for example via integer indexing. But here's one way using `eval`. Note there are [security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) involved, so be sure your inputs are safe.

```
x = ["zubin", "viral", "rushil"]
param = ["x[0]", "x[1]", "x[2]"]

for p in param:
    print(eval(p))

zubin
viral
rushil
```